# Is it safe to use AngularJS's $window object?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

As `$window` is wrapper to the Javascript's `window` object which is a global variable. Does the `$window` too takes the data globally to the browser and is it safe to use? I'm developing a *back navigation* functionality, is it safe to use `$window.history` object?

Answer (score 2):

$window is always safer than the window object, but for back navigation, I would strongly suggest using [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute), which gives you all you would need and more out of the box. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to not use $window, it is preferred. same as it is better to use 'angular.forEach', rather than just 'for x in y'